# Redirect to a certain page then perform an event or action

Tags: javascript, redirect

I have a button with an onlick event that when triggered, has to redirect to a certain page, and add a class to a certain element.

Using the code:

`window.location.href = "http://localhost:8000/dashboard";`

`$('p').addClass('active');`,

I've successfully managed to redirect it but the event was not performed.  Is this even possible because it refreshes the DOM after redirecting. Thanks.

Comment: while redirecting, add a query param(eg: ?active=true) with appropriate name and on page load, run the required javascript if you find the query param in the url.

Answer (score 0):

You will not be able to manipulate DOM elements on other pages during navigation as code after the redirect will not be executed. Instead listen to events on the page you are redirecting to and determine from there on how to apply your `active` class.

Comment: I've read about saving objects in a cookie and call upon the certain cookie after redirecting. I'm new to this so this is really giving me a hard time.

Comment: @DaveMoreno It really depends on the framework of the web application you're using. Much like @alert_xss answer. I notice that you tagged your question under `laravel` so I would recommend seeing if there is a `laravel` specific implementation you could adapt.

Answer (score 0):

**The normal flow of JavaScript execution is broken when executing a full page navigation.**  That means that JavaScript on the first page won't be able to modify the DOM on the second since the first page is no longer being executed by the browser after navigation.

There are some ways around this in practice, although I'm not sure if they are beyond the scope of what you might want to consider.  **The old way of doing this would be to use an IFRAME tag to load your content in to, and execute all your scripts from the outer context.**  If the pages are all on the same domain, the outer page can reach into the frame and cause them to navigate or even modify their DOM.

**A more modern approach is to pick a "single page app" technology like [Angular](https://angular.io/guide/router) or [React](https://reactjs.org/community/routing.html).  In those languages page navigation doesn't have to redirect the page** in the traditional sense so execution flow isn't interrupted in the same way.  This is a fairly heavy handed approach though and since you mentioned PHP, you may not find those as appealing.

Since you are using PHP you could pass parameters to the second page to indicate a change needed to be made and handle it in PHP, such as http://example.com/secondPage.php?useOtherCSS=true.  Just a thought, even though it wouldn't use JavaScript it would play toward your goal.